# How do I create a SQL SELECT statement that has two fields in one table referencing the same field in another table

Tags: select, foreign-keys, mariadb

I am thinking this is a simple answer for those with more SQL experience. I have two tables. Two fields in one table (website) reference one field in the other (ip_address). I am having trouble creating the SELECT command that will print the output below:

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from website;
+----+-----------+--------------+----------------+
| id | node_name | primary_host | secondary_host |
+----+-----------+--------------+----------------+
|  1 | site1     |            1 |              2 |
|  2 | site2     |            3 |              4 |
+----+-----------+--------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from ip_address;
+----+-------------+
| id | ip          |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | 192.168.1.1 |
|  2 | 192.168.1.2 |
|  3 | 192.168.1.3 |
|  4 | 192.168.1.4 |
+----+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Output Required:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| node_name | ip          | ip          |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| site1     | 192.168.1.1 | 192.168.1.2 |
| site2     | 192.168.1.3 | 192.168.1.4 |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I think you are looking for some JOINs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should solve your problem.

```
select v1.node_name, v2.ip, v3.ip 
from website v1 
left join ip_address v2 on v1.primary_host = v2.id 
left join ip_address v3 on v1.secondary_host = v3.id
```

Comment: I'm glad! If an answer is helpful and solves your problem, you should mark it as useful and select it as the answer. Just incase other users in the future have a similar problem.